# I tryied to in insert and select in the same time in mysql PyQt5

Tags: mysql, pyqt5

I tryied to in insert and select in the same time in mysql PyQt5 but the program didn't work.
the program is working till i tryied to insert and selectin the same time in MySql.

This is the code before I got the issue :

```
        self.groupe.currentTextChanged.connect(self.grouchan)

def grouchan(self):
        global id_filint
        qidmat = "select Id_filiere from filiereacademiquecsv where Libelle_filiere_francais=%s"
        ridmat = (self.txt_filiere.text(),)
        mycursor.execute(qidmat, ridmat)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
        for idf in myresult:
            id_filint = idf

        qmat = "select distinct Id_matiere from matiereunité m inner join filiereacademiquecsv f on f.Id_filiere=m.Id_filieranalytiq where Id_filieranalytiq=%s and Libelle_matiere_francais=%s"
        rnp1 = (id_filint, self.matiere.currentText())
        mycursor.execute(qmat,rnp1)
        myresult1 = mycursor.fetchone()
        for i in myresult1:
            print(i)

        qgrp = "select idgroupe from groupcyclniv where LibGroupe=%s"
        rnp3 = (self.groupe.currentText(),)
        mycursor.execute(qgrp, rnp3)
        myresult2 = mycursor.fetchone()
        for v in myresult2:
            print(v)
```

This is where I got the issue.
This is where I tryied to insert and select :

```
        qnp = "insert into mobile (Id_eleve, nomprenom, Id_matiere) SELECT a.IdEleve,e.nomprenom,m.Id_matiere FROM asselevgroupevf a inner join eleve e inner join matiereunité m on a.IdEleve = e.Ideleve where a.IdGroup =%s and Id_matiere =%s"
        rnp1 = (v, i)
        mycursor.execute(rnp1, qnp)
        mydb.commit()
```

Comment: provide complete error message text received from MySQL server.

Comment: I dont have issue in mysql. The requet MySql is workin i have the issue in Python

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mycursor.execute(qnp, rnp1)`?

Comment: Yes, it is the issue thank you.

Comment: @AmineOmar I suggest you to use more verbose variables. Names like "qmat", "qnp", "rnp1" are too short and similar, do not make clear what they represent, and they are more prone to errors caused by misreading (which is probably what happened to you). I'll mark this post for closure, as this kind of issues (not reproducible or caused by typos) are considered off topic for SO. If you want, you can delete it.

Comment: ok thank you for helping.